# Unable to thread comments because of custom comments.php file

Tags: themes, comments

Hey i tried using wordpress threaded comment feature but didn't work coz of custom theme. 
I have tried wp threaded comments plugin it works like a charm but unfortunately it has a conflict with the FV community news plugin, It shows a reply button on the community news area/widget.

So i tried to do it manually... no luck. can anyone suggest me or point meto somewhere i can get some data to fix this.

My wordpress version is 3.0.4
cheers

Current COmment . php

```
<?php // Do not delete these lines
    if (!empty($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']) && 'comments.php' == basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']))
        die ('Please do not load this page directly. Thanks!');

    if (!empty($post->post_password)) { // if there's a password
        if ($_COOKIE['wp-postpass_' . COOKIEHASH] != $post->post_password) {  // and it doesn't match the cookie
            ?>

            <p>This post is password protected. Enter the password to view comments.</p>

            <?php
            return;
        }
    }

    /* This variable is for alternating comment background */
    $oddcomment = 'alt';
?>
<?php if ( $comments ) : ?>
<!-- You can start editing here. -->

            <?php $urlHome = get_bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>
                        <div class="box post-comments" id="comments">
                <div class="content">
                    <h4>Awesome Comments!</h4>

                    <?php foreach ($comments as $comment) : ?>
                   <?php $comment_type = get_comment_type(); ?>
<?php if($comment_type == 'comment') { ?>
                     <div id="comment-<?php comment_ID() ?>" class="fl ar">

                        <div class="pic"><?php echo get_avatar( $comment, 80, $default = $urlHome . '/images/default_avatar_visitor.gif' ); ?></div>
                        <div class="comm-name"><a href="<?php comment_author_url(); ?>" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"><?php comment_author(); ?></a></div>
                        <div class="comm-date"><small><em><?php the_time('m.d.y') ?></em></small></div>
                     </div>
                     <div class="fr">
                       <div class="box2 <?php echo $oddcomment; ?>">
                         <?php comment_text() ?>
                       </div><!--/box2 -->
                     </div>   <div class="fix"></div>

                        <?php $oddcomment = ( empty( $oddcomment ) ) ? 'alt' : ''; ?> 
                        <?php } /* End of is_comment statement */ ?>
                                    <?php endforeach; // end for each comment ?>

                </div> </div>
               <div class="box">
               <div class="content">
<h3 id="trackbacks">Trackbacks</h3>
<ol class="trackbacksol">
    <?php //Displays trackbacks only
    foreach ($comments as $comment) : ?>
        <?php $comment_type = get_comment_type(); ?>
        <?php if($comment_type != 'comment') { ?>
        <li><?php comment_author_link() ?></li>
    <?php }  endforeach; ?>
</ol>
</div></div>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if ('open' == $post->comment_status) : ?> 
            <div id="respond" class="box post-comments">
                <div class="content">
                    <h4>Leave Your Response</h2>

                    <?php if ( get_option('comment_registration') && !$user_ID ) : ?>
                    <p>You must be <a href="<?php echo get_option('siteurl'); ?>/wp-login.php?redirect_to=<?php echo urlencode(get_permalink()); ?>">logged in</a> to post a comment.</p>
                    <?php else : ?>

                    <div class="fl">
                        <?php if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {?>
                        <div class="pic"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/default_avatar_visitor.gif" alt="" /></div>
                        <?  } else { ?>
                         <p>Your Name: </p>
                        <p style="margin-top:9px;">Your Email: </p>
                        <p style="margin-top:12px;">Website: </p>
                        <p style="margin-top:15px;">Comments: </p> <? } ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="fr">
                        <form action="<?php echo get_option('siteurl'); ?>/wp-comments-post.php" method="post" id="commentform">
                            <fieldset class="message">
                            <?php if ( $user_ID ) : ?>
                                <p>Logged in as <a href="<?php echo get_option('siteurl'); ?>/wp-admin/profile.php"><?php echo $user_identity; ?></a>. <a href="<?php echo get_option('siteurl'); ?>/wp-login.php?action=logout" title="Log out of this account">Log out &raquo;</a></p>
                            <?php else : ?>
                            <div>
                                <input name="author" id="author" type="text" value="" />
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <input name="email" id="email" type="text" value="" />
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <input name="url" id="url" type="text" value="" />
                            </div>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                            <div class="textarea">
                                <textarea name="comment" id="comment" cols="" rows=""></textarea>
                            </div>
                            <div class="submit">
                                <input name="submit" id="submit" type="image" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/btn-submit.gif" value="Send" class="btn"  />
                            </div>
                            <div class="notice">* Name, Email, Comment are Required</div>
                            <input type="hidden" name="comment_post_ID" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" />
                            <?php do_action('comment_form', $post->ID); ?>
                            </fieldset>
                        </form>
                        <?php endif; // If registration required and not logged in ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="fix"></div>
                </div>
                <!--/content -->
            </div>
            <!--/box -->
            <?php endif; // if you delete this the sky will fall on your head ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it not work because theme is old or simply coded in incompatible way?

There is this article in Codex that might be relevant - [Migrating Plugins and Themes to 2.7/Enhanced Comment Display](http://codex.wordpress.org/Migrating_Plugins_and_Themes_to_2.7/Enhanced_Comment_Display).

Otherwise I'd take a look at some modern theme (like Twenty Ten) and see how is it properly coded for current WordPress version.

Comment: Hello, i have already seen that link and tried to implement some stuf from other articles as well but no help, im adding a copy of my theme in top edit!

Comment: @Ayaz Malik yeah, seems to be old stuff... Had you tried looking at any modern theme? Basically most of that stuff goes away and gets replaced with [`wp_list_comments()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_comments) and [`comment_form()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comment_form).

Comment: hmm i c, i haven't and im not a wordpress guy first time editing wordperss, so i guess i have to do my research now lol.

Comment: @Ayaz Malik well, I _could_ update your template - which will make me very bored and you no closer to understanding what is going on in your theme. But as I recommended above - I think it's better if you take a look at `comments.php` in modern theme (again - Twenty Ten is kinda official one), try to understand the difference and maybe ask more specific questions about mechanics of comments. Remember - this site is mostly about helping other people **learn**, not do something instead of them. :)

Comment: yup i totally understand and its fun learning on my own thts why i never put anythign at first just as suggestion as i am a php coder :D . i have already implemented it and working on the css, here is my test site. http://www.zzznetworks.com/blog/2011/01/22/download-test-page/ take a look :) thanks for pointing to right direction